# Adding a definition of a word in a sentence is confusing the reader

Tags: grammar, sentence

### Problem description

In the following paragraph. I am talking about the update of an Entity Linking system by using a Supervised Model. I also added a definition of what **Entity Linking** is in order to help the reader understand what I am talking about.

> The objective of our work is twofold: first to update the existing
> Entity Linking system which represents the task of linking a word in a
> piece of text, to an ‘entity’ or ‘concept’ from a knowledge base by
> using a Supervised Model well suited for Large-Scale datasets and
> second to incorporate the Entity Linking system in applications such
> as the study of Temporal Data and Sentiment Analysis in forums.

---

### Question

My question is the following: Is it clear that we are updating the system by using a Supervised model? I feel that adding the following definition

> which represents the task of linking a word in a piece of text, to an
> ‘entity’ or ‘concept’ from a knowledge base

is confusing to the reader. The reader has to read to whole definition before getting to how system is updated. But then again the definition is important

Comment: The reason your text is confusing to the reader is because you're trying to cram too much information into too few sentences. But this is essentially *writing advice*, which I think is off topic.

Comment: Proof-reading/ rephrasing advice may be OT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parentheses and comma-addition/removal would help:

*"The objective of our work is twofold: first to update the existing Entity Linking system (which represents the task of linking a word in a piece of text to an ‘entity’ or ‘concept’ from a knowledge base), by using a Supervised Model well suited for Large-Scale datasets, and, second, to incorporate the Entity Linking system in applications such as the study of Temporal Data and Sentiment Analysis in forums."*

This helps the reader break it down as follows:

```
The objective of our work is twofold: 
first 
to update the existing Entity Linking system 
(which represents the task of linking a word in a piece of text to an ‘entity’ or ‘concept’ from a knowledge base), 
by using a Supervised Model well suited for Large-Scale datasets,
and, second,
to incorporate the Entity Linking system in applications such as the study of Temporal Data and Sentiment Analysis in forums.
```

Which I assume is what is required.

Comment: thank you. I feel that it's clear .I am not that good at English grammar. but yes the parentheses did change everything.

Comment: @HaniGoc You're right about the parentheses changing things, but I'm not sure it's for the better.  You have two thoughts -- what the work is (update) and what the objectives are (using a Supervised Model and incorporation in apps).  So use two sentences.  You can define an ELS in the first.  You can have the second introduce a bullet list of two items.  What's the difference between "represents the task of linking" and "links"?  Is 'concept' an appositive?  If so, it should be set off by commas.  If not, you've used *entity* to define *Entity*. And *, and,* is inartful.